# Size of the data decide linearity of a mathematical model built around it?

Tags: linear-algebra

I read this para in a [Linear Algebra Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321385179)

> Leontief, who was awarded the nobel prize in Economics Science,
>   opened the door to a new era in mathematical modeling in economics.
>   His efforts at Harvard in 1949 marked one of the most significant uses
>   of computers to analyze what was then a large scale mathematical
>   model. Since that time, researchers in may fields have employed
>   computers to analyze mathematical models. **Because of the massive
>   amount of data involved, the models are usually linear; that is, they
>   are described by a system of linear equations.**

What has size of the data to do with the linearity of the model used to describe it ?

Comment: It is hard to tell from this fragment alone, but one might assume that the amount of data would have made non-linear models intractable.

Comment: Linear models have a closed form solution (e.g. for OLS regressions we know $\hat{\beta}=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$ whereas for non-linear models one typically needs to resort to numerical methods in order to find a solution. The larger the dataset, the longer this process will take.